# Using ingress in Minishift

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, minishift

I'm having an issue to use an Ingress in minishift. This example [configuring certificate based mutual tls](https://medium.com/@awkwardferny/configuring-certificate-based-mutual-authentication-with-kubernetes-ingress-nginx-20e7e38fdfca)

works perfectly fine in minikube, after I have enabled in minikube ingress addon by running `minikube addons enable ingress`

I can't do same thing as there're no `ingress` addon in minishift. I tried to download and install it with no success.

```sh
john@alaptop:~/MutualAuthentication$ minishift addons list
- admin-user             : disabled P(0)
- admissions-webhook         : disabled P(0)
- anyuid             : disabled P(0)
- che                : disabled P(0)
- htpasswd-identity-provider     : disabled P(0)
- redhat-registry-login      : disabled P(0)
- registry-route         : disabled P(0)
- xpaas              : disabled P(0)
john@alaptop:~/MutualAuthentication$ minikube addons list
- addon-manager: enabled
- dashboard: disabled
- default-storageclass: enabled
- efk: disabled
- freshpod: disabled
- gvisor: disabled
- heapster: disabled
- ingress: enabled
- logviewer: disabled
- metrics-server: disabled
- nvidia-driver-installer: disabled
- nvidia-gpu-device-plugin: disabled
- registry: disabled
- registry-creds: disabled
- storage-provisioner: enabled
- storage-provisioner-gluster: disabled
john@alaptop:~/MutualAuthentication$
```

In [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.1/networking/ingress-operator.html) the difference with my ingress is the apiVersion is different, i.e. instead of `config.openshift.io/v1` it has `extensions/v1beta1`.
I believe there ingress is HAProxy based, where I need ngnix ingress.

Then after I started this

```
oc describe --namespace=openshift-ingress-operator ingresscontroller/default
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "ingresscontroller"
```

I again thinking that ingress needs to be installed either via addon or some plugin. How I can do this?

I'm using Minishift 3.11.

Comment: I could not find anything about ingress on minishift. As i could read [there](https://blog.openshift.com/kubernetes-ingress-vs-openshift-route/) there is something like ingress,created by openshift called route, registry-route in your minishift addons.

Comment: How did you solve this?